# FaceBook: posting same status to user wall getting error

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

my code work fine but i have issue . when i click again to post in the same list item getting force close . if i click in another list item will post successfully . basicly can't post same text1 again Without posting another text and back to post text1 .

```
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
private static final String PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY = "pendingPublishReauthorization";
private boolean pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
private static final String TAG = "FaceBook";
private Boolean isShared;

private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        pendingPublishReauthorization = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(
                PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, false);
    }
    ls = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    ls.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            0, ITEMS));


}

    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data) {
            Log.e("Activity", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
            Log.i("Activity", "Success!");
        }
    });
}

     private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<String> iTEMS) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, iTEMS);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_item, parent,
                    false);

        }
        tv_content_item = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_content);

        tv_content_item.setText(ITEMS.get(position));
        tv_content_item.setTag(position);
        tv_content_item.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "fonts/Hayah.otf"));

        TextView tv_counter = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.text_counter);
        tv_counter.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));

        Button facebook = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.btn_share_face);

        facebook.setOnClickListener(ViewActivity.this);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ITEMS.size();
    }

}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final TextView tv = (TextView) ls.findViewWithTag(ls
            .getPositionForView(v));

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btn_share_face:


            if(!isShared){

        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

            // callback when session changes state
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception) {
                if (session.isOpened()) {
                    isShared=true;
                       publishStory(tv.getText().toString());

                }
            }
        });

        }else{
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

            if (session.isOpened()) {
                   publishStory(tv.getText().toString());


        }
        }
        break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();

}



@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();

}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, pendingPublishReauthorization);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private void publishStory(String txt) {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null){

        // Check for publish permissions    
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                    .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
            return;
        }

        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("message", txt);

        Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                JSONObject graphResponse = response
                                           .getGraphObject()
                                           .getInnerJSONObject();
                String postId = null;
                try {
                    postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG,
                        "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
                }
                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                if (error != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(ViewActivity.this
                         .getApplicationContext(),
                         error.getErrorMessage(),
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ViewActivity.this
                             .getApplicationContext(), 
                             postId,
                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };

        Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, 
                              HttpMethod.POST, callback);

        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();
    }

}
private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
    for (String string : subset) {
        if (!superset.contains(string)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

my logcat

```
01-15 07:10:29.771: W/dalvikvm(4584): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e8c898)
01-15 07:10:29.771: E/AndroidRuntime(4584): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 07:10:29.771: E/AndroidRuntime(4584): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-15 07:10:29.771: E/AndroidRuntime(4584):     at com.droidibuilders.aqual_alolma.ViewActivity$4.onCompleted(ViewActivity.java:352)
01-15 07:10:29.771: E/AndroidRuntime(4584):     at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1669)
01-15 07:10:29.771: E/AndroidRuntime(4584):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-15 07:10:29.771: E/AndroidRuntime(4584):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-15 07:10:29.771: E/AndroidRuntime(4584):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-15 07:10:29.771: E/AndroidRuntime(4584):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5450)
01-15 07:10:29.771: E/AndroidRuntime(4584):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 07:10:29.771: E/AndroidRuntime(4584):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-15 07:10:29.771: E/AndroidRuntime(4584):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
01-15 07:10:29.771: E/AndroidRuntime(4584):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
01-15 07:10:29.771: E/AndroidRuntime(4584):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your logcat along with the line number

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine don't have any issue with the code. The only thing is `facebook SDK` does not allow to post `multiple status with the same text`. and there is timeline of i think one minute. You can post the same status more than once after `1minute`. If you change the text lets say try to `append the current time with your post text` so that the two status is never same. And you can post now many times the same status but the time would be different.

Comment: I am not sure about the time line though.

Comment: if i edit my code by this  >>>  Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
         postParams.putString("message", txt);
         postParams.putString("name", getString(R.string.app_name));
         postParams.putString("link", "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.droidibuilders.aqual_alolma");
 the problem will gone .. why ?

Comment: sorry Didn't get you, what do you want to say ?

Comment: you still can't understand me ? when add a link to post will post without any wait

Comment: What is your `line 352` in your `aqual_alolma` activity ? As in your logcat suggest when your app getting failed, you were getting `NullPointerException` so may be at your `line 352` may be your postParam would be null. Just guessing. Can you tell about the line no 352.

Comment: JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
this is the line

Comment: Have you debugged your app? I think your `response` variable was null. Which causes this error. Are you getting the same error now?

Answer (score 0):

thank you .. i edited my onComplete and work fine .

```
 public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                if (error != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(ViewActivity.this
                         .getApplicationContext(),
                        getString(R.string.post_faild),
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ViewActivity.this
                             .getApplicationContext(), 
                             getString(R.string.post_succeed),
                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };
```